# Expo app rejected for Invalid Binary for WebView and user-fonts

Tags: ios, react-native, fonts, expo

I tried uploading an app I created with Expo onto the Apple App Store and 30 minutes later I get an email saying my project has `Invalid Binary` they provided two reasons behind why it was rejected. 
**Problem 1.** because `Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs`

However from what I've seen on other forums this doesn't usually result in a rejection for Expo projects with SDK ranging from SDK 28 to 35 (my project is running on 33).

**Problem 2** because `Invalid entitlement - The com.apple.developer.user-fonts is valid only for apps build with SDK 13 or later.`

The solution I've found on other forums say that I should go into the developer console and uncheck the 'fonts' section in the Apple Developer section. Upon doing this the problem still persists

I'm not sure what I can do now, I need help

My project is running on SDK 33

Answer (score 1):

This issue is currently under discussion. There are reports that the update to `SDK35` has been resolved. We recommend that you update to `SDK35`

[expo forums about received-mail-from-apple-about-the-deprecated-api-uiwebview](https://forums.expo.io/t/received-mail-from-apple-about-the-deprecated-api-uiwebview/27117/22)